# I'm not experienced enough to know if an answer is correct or not. Should I accept it?

Tags: discussion, answers

The following question illustrates my point very well: [*Can going into “suspend” have negative effects on applications?*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320159/can-going-into-suspend-have-negative-effects-on-applications)

I'm not familiar enough with the CPU and how the kernel works under the hood to know the right answer (which is exactly why I asked the question). Moreover, unlike [questions about code](https://stackoverflow.com/), there is no way to "test" if the provided answer is correct or not. I just have to rely on the fact that the answerer knows what he is talking about.

Should I accept the answer as "correct" even though I have no way of knowing if it is? Or should I leave it open and let upvotes and comments by more experienced determine accuracy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question involves more in depth knowledge about power management, hardware involved in the process and software that manages it. The answers provided cover most cases, but will still vary depending on hardware, system and even software applications involved. If you feel an answer gives you a better understanding of your question or answers your doubt somehow, then I would accept the answer. Accepting does not mean, at least in this cases, the answer is the correct, but it does mean it was the most useful answer you could receive.

For what I could read, all answers are great and give you what each user knows about the issue.

Answer (score -1):

When you mark an answer as accepted it means that it solved your problem/question/doubt/whatever_you_were_asking. You can leave the answer there until you find time to test if what the answer says actually solves your problem, if you still have doubts you can comment the answer asking for clarification what each thing do.

Anyways, whenever you feel that the answer answers your question, mark it as accepted.

<sub>tl;dr finally!</sub>

---

This answer is meant to be canonical.